# Getting 'No module named numpy' error while installing 'lap' module, how to resolve this?

Tags: python, numpy

I have checked all the conditions and also installed all the necessary modules

here is the text of error-

```
Collecting lap
  Using cached lap-0.4.0.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Partial import of lap during the build process.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 127, in get_numpy_status
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 149, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-59qch528\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 380, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-59qch528\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-59qch528\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 236, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 220, in setup_package
      ImportError: lap requires numpy, please "pip install numpy".
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], read how to [ask] and how to produce a [mre]. Don't post links to images of code or errors. Now, have you tried installing `numpy` like the error suggests: `ImportError: lap requires numpy, please "pip install numpy"`?

Comment: I see that you claim to have "checked all the conditions and also installed all the necessary modules." Please provide the output of `pip freeze`, and the exact command used to attempt to install `lap`.

Comment: Have you tried installing numpy?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to install easy_ViTPose requirements. I solved it by removing lap from requirements.txt, then installed all packages with `pip install -r requirements.txt`. After that I called `pip install lap==0.4.0` and it worked.